# How to convert Dataset<Row> to List<GenericRecord>

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, apache-iceberg

Would like to know how to convert `Dataset<Row>` to `List<GenericRecord>`.

I'm speaking on:

```
org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord

org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Dataset<Row> data = spark.sql(SQL_QUERY)
```

The result is different per `SQL_QUERY`, therefore the schema can be different per use case.

Important to know that I'm reading from an `Iceberg` table, saving files as `.avro` under the hood.

My current thinking is to find a way to convert each `Row` of the `Dataset<Row>` to `bytes[]` and then to:

```
public static List<GenericRecord> deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
    List<GenericRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        DataFileReader<GenericRecord> reader = new DataFileReader<>(
                new SeekableByteArrayInput(bytes),
                new ExpectedSpecificDatumReader()
        );

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            records.add(reader.next(null));
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
    return records;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iceberg has an utility class that may help you: [`org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkValueConverter`](https://github.com/apache/iceberg/blob/master/spark/v3.3/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/iceberg/spark/SparkValueConverter.java) located at `iceberg/spark/v3.3/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/iceberg/spark/SparkValueConverter.java` in the project hierarchy.

Here is the class, in case it gets deleted/moved from the GitHub link above.

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
package org.apache.iceberg.spark;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.iceberg.Schema;
import org.apache.iceberg.data.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.iceberg.data.Record;
import org.apache.iceberg.relocated.com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.apache.iceberg.relocated.com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import org.apache.iceberg.types.Type;
import org.apache.iceberg.types.Types;
import org.apache.iceberg.util.ByteBuffers;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils;

/** A utility class that converts Spark values to Iceberg's internal representation. */
public class SparkValueConverter {

  private SparkValueConverter() {}

  public static Record convert(Schema schema, Row row) {
    return convert(schema.asStruct(), row);
  }

  public static Object convert(Type type, Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
      return null;
    }

    switch (type.typeId()) {
      case STRUCT:
        return convert(type.asStructType(), (Row) object);

      case LIST:
        List<Object> convertedList = Lists.newArrayList();
        List<?> list = (List<?>) object;
        for (Object element : list) {
          convertedList.add(convert(type.asListType().elementType(), element));
        }
        return convertedList;

      case MAP:
        Map<Object, Object> convertedMap = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
        Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) object;
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
          convertedMap.put(
              convert(type.asMapType().keyType(), entry.getKey()),
              convert(type.asMapType().valueType(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return convertedMap;

      case DATE:
        // if spark.sql.datetime.java8API.enabled is set to true, java.time.LocalDate
        // for Spark SQL DATE type otherwise java.sql.Date is returned.
        return DateTimeUtils.anyToDays(object);
      case TIMESTAMP:
        // if spark.sql.datetime.java8API.enabled is set to true, java.time.Instant
        // for Spark SQL TIMESTAMP type is returned otherwise java.sql.Timestamp is returned.
        return DateTimeUtils.anyToMicros(object);
      case BINARY:
        return ByteBuffer.wrap((byte[]) object);
      case INTEGER:
        return ((Number) object).intValue();
      case BOOLEAN:
      case LONG:
      case FLOAT:
      case DOUBLE:
      case DECIMAL:
      case STRING:
      case FIXED:
        return object;
      default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not a supported type: " + type);
    }
  }

  private static Record convert(Types.StructType struct, Row row) {
    if (row == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Record record = GenericRecord.create(struct);
    List<Types.NestedField> fields = struct.fields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i += 1) {
      Types.NestedField field = fields.get(i);

      Type fieldType = field.type();

      switch (fieldType.typeId()) {
        case STRUCT:
          record.set(i, convert(fieldType.asStructType(), row.getStruct(i)));
          break;
        case LIST:
          record.set(i, convert(fieldType.asListType(), row.getList(i)));
          break;
        case MAP:
          record.set(i, convert(fieldType.asMapType(), row.getJavaMap(i)));
          break;
        default:
          record.set(i, convert(fieldType, row.get(i)));
      }
    }
    return record;
  }

  public static Object convertToSpark(Type type, Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
      return null;
    }

    switch (type.typeId()) {
      case STRUCT:
      case LIST:
      case MAP:
        return new UnsupportedOperationException("Complex types currently not supported");
      case DATE:
        return DateTimeUtils.daysToLocalDate((int) object);
      case TIMESTAMP:
        Types.TimestampType ts = (Types.TimestampType) type.asPrimitiveType();
        if (ts.shouldAdjustToUTC()) {
          return DateTimeUtils.microsToInstant((long) object);
        } else {
          return DateTimeUtils.microsToLocalDateTime((long) object);
        }
      case BINARY:
        return ByteBuffers.toByteArray((ByteBuffer) object);
      case INTEGER:
      case BOOLEAN:
      case LONG:
      case FLOAT:
      case DOUBLE:
      case DECIMAL:
      case STRING:
      case FIXED:
        return object;
      default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not a supported type: " + type);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This link may not always be available. When spark3.3 is removed, it will not exist, but the class will most likely remain. You can search for it directly in the code repository.